# wordpress failed to open stream error whereas working nice in localhost

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, warnings, require-once

i am doing in wordpress 5.3 the pulgin for woocommerce is showing this msgs

> Warning: require_once(/home/sitename/public_html/1): failed to open
>   stream: Success in
>   /home/sitename/public_html/wp-content/plugins/learnpress-woo-payment/incs/load.php
>   on line 80
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '1' 
>   (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/sitename/public_html/wp-content/plugins/learnpress-woo-payment/incs/load.php
>   on line 80

above occurs on live server whereas same plugin and everything works very well in localhost

**i m working on https:// secure url**

please help

Comment: Are you sure you have that file in the server you are deploying?

Comment: load.php is there, btw ; which files do you mean?

Comment: That your error message is telling you and must learn to understand: `Failed opening required '1' `

Comment: I checked and re uploaded the files , its something else

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your wp-config.php file (in your root directory):

```
define("LP_ADDON_WOO_PAYMENT_PATH", "/home/sitename/public_html/wp-content/plugins/learnpress-woo-payment");
```

This is a long shot, but it should at least give us a different error. It sounds like you migrated from localhost to a production server, but either some configurations are now incorrect, or some files were copied over incorrectly.

The error message tells us that your learnpress-woo-payment plugin is trying to load a file called "1", and other details of the error indicate that the plugin was not given an exact path. I assume that "1" is actually a boolean, so the plugin is somehow ending up with a TRUE in place of a file path... so, we take a look at the code for the plugin:

```
if ( $this->is_enabled() && $this->woo_checkout_enabled() ) {
        // WooCommerce checkout
        $checkout = require_once LP_ADDON_WOO_PAYMENT_PATH . '/incs/class-lp-wc-checkout.php';
        if ( file_exists( $checkout ) ) {
                require_once $checkout;
        }
}
```

...this doesn't quite match what I expected to see (line 80 is the comment), but it does seem like: if the first require_once fails in a way that returns SUCCESS (it does due to an [irregular bug with PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45130)) then $checkout becomes TRUE... which apparently exists, so we attempt to include it again! Not great code...

Comment: Notice: Constant LP_ADDON_WOO_PAYMENT_PATH already defined in /home/sitename/public_html/wp-content/plugins/learnpress-woo-payment/learnpress-woo-payment.php on line 18
-- all other errors are below ---
Warning: require_once(/home/sitename/public_html/1): failed to open stream: Success in /home/sitename/public_html/wp-content/plugins/learnpress-woo-payment/incs/load.php on line 80

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '1' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear') in /home/sitename/public_html/wp-content/plugins/learnpress-woo-payment/incs/load.php on line 80

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

> Websites behind load balancers or reverse proxies that support
>   HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO can be fixed by adding the following code to
>   the wp-config.php file, above the require_once call:

if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) && 'https' == $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}

[Here the link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/ssl-and-https/)